# Pandas percentage calculation with groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame in pandas which have following format.

```
 coupon_applied    coupon_type    dish_id     dish_name     dish_price  
0            Yes      Rs 20 off     012     Paneer Biryani         110   

dish_quant_bought  dish_quantity dish_substitute dish_type 
0         50              2             Yes       Veg   

      rder_time            order_id  order_lat    year  
0 2015-12-05 16:30:04.345  order_1   73.955741    2015   

     month       day             time  
0    12       Saturday     16:30:04.345000
```

I want to calculate dish selling rate for a particular time interval.
dish selling rate = (dish_quant)/(dish_quant_bought)

I am doing following..

```
    df_final[(df_final['time'] > datetime.time(16,30)) & (df_final['time'] < datetime.time(16,35))].groupby('dish_name').sum()['dish_quantity']
```

Which gives me following

```
dish_name
Chicken Biryani         2
Chicken Tikka Masala    2
Mutton Biryani          2
Paneer Biryani          2
```

But I am unable to divide dish quantity sold by dish quantity bought..
How to do it? please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do it very simple:

```
df = df_final[(df_final['time'] > datetime.time(16,30)) & (df_final['time'] < datetime.time(16,35))].groupby('dish_name').sum()

df['dish_selling_rate'] = df['dish_quantity'] / df['dish_quant_bought']

print df.head(5)
```